# Unfold in all directions

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

#### Input:

A string

#### Output:

1) First we take remove character at the end of the input-string until we are left with a length that is a square (i.e. 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, etc.)
So `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` (length 26) becomes `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy` (length 25).

2) Then we put this in a square, one line at  a time, left to right:

```
abcde
fghij
klmno
pqrst
uvwxy
```

3) We fold it in all four directions, like this (we keep unfolding until the outer folded 'block' has no inner characters to unfold anymore):

```
      m
     qrs
     l n
     ghi
    abcde
 ihgf   jihg
mn lk   on lm
 srqp   tsrq
    uvwxy
     qrs
     l n
     ghi
      m
```

Some things to note, when we fold outward, we basically mirror like this (numbers added as clarification, which represents the 'indexes' in these examples):

When we fold out the left side:

```
 123    to:   321 123
fghij         ihgf   j
```

When we fold the right side:

```
 123    to:    123 321
fghij         f   jihg
```

When we fold upwards:

```
            3q
            2l
            1g
  b   to:    b
 1g         1
 2l         2
 3q         3
  v          v
```

When we fold downwards:

```
 b          b
1g         1
2l         2
3q         3
 v   to:    v
           3q
           2l
           1g
```

#### Challenge rules:

- You can assume the input will always have at least 1 character (which will also be the output).
- Output format is flexible, so you can print to STDOUT or STDERR; return as string-array/list or character 2D-array; single string with new-lines; etc.
- The input will only contain alphanumeric characters (`a-zA-Z0-9`)
- You can also use a non-alphanumeric character to fill up the spaces in and/or around the ASCII-art output, like a dot `.`.
- Trailing spaces and a single trailing new-line are optional.
- We continue unfolding until the outer folded 'block' has no more centers to unfold.

#### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer, so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code.
- Also, please add an explanation if necessary.

#### Test cases:

```
Input: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
Output:
      m
     qrs
     l n
     ghi
    abcde
 ihgf   jihg
mn lk   on lm
 srqp   tsrq
    uvwxy
     qrs
     l n
     ghi
      m

Input: A
Ouput:
A

Input: ThisIsATest
Output:
  I
 Thi
Is sI
 ATe
  I

Input: HowAboutAVeryLongExampleWhichIsAlsoAnEvenSquareInsteadOfOddOneAndExceeds64Chars
Output:

               An
               ch
              xamp
              i  I
              o  E
              quar
             steadO
             S    e
             s    v
             h    s
             E    l
             VeryLo
            HowAbout
      oLyreVA      noLyreV
  xampl    Eg      el    Examp
hci  Is    hW      As    hi  Ihc
nAo  Ev    sl      ev    so  EnA
  quare    Sn      Ie    Squar
      Odaetsn      fOdaets
            OddOneAn
             steadO
             S    e
             s    v
             h    s
             E    l
             VeryLo
              xamp
              i  I
              o  E
              quar
               An
               ch

Input: Lenght7
Output:
Le
ng

Input: abc
Output:
a
```

Comment: there's a mistake in the test for "HowAboutAVeryLongExampleWhichIsAlsoAnEvenSquareInsteadOfOddOneAndExceeds64Chars": 'h'->'i' near the bottom of the output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 75 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
l√u²m√lH»{ā;l⁾:A∫Ba{bIwFIWhFbž;FIbI@ž}};}¹K⁴{ē2\⌡±e{@Κ};⁴┼┼};0E{ē2\⌡№:h++}╚
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JTJDbCV1MjIxQXUlQjJtJXUyMjFBbEglQkIlN0IldTAxMDElM0JsJXUyMDdFJTNBQSV1MjIyQkJhJTdCYkl3RklXaEZiJXUwMTdFJTNCRkliSUAldTAxN0UlN0QlN0QlM0IlN0QlQjlLJXUyMDc0JTdCJXUwMTEzMiU1QyV1MjMyMSVCMWUlN0JAJXUwMzlBJTdEJTNCJXUyMDc0JXUyNTNDJXUyNTNDJTdEJTNCMEUlN0IldTAxMTMyJTVDJXUyMzIxJXUyMTE2JTNBaCsrJTdEJXUyNTVB,inputs=SG93QWJvdXRBVmVyeUxvbmdFeGFtcGxlV2hpY2hJc0Fsc29BbkV2ZW5QcmltZUluc3RlYWRPZk9kZE9uZUFuZEV4Y2VlZHM2NENoYXJz)

This expects the input on the stack, so for ease-of-use I added `,` at the start. That can cause issues if the input contains only numbers so [here](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=MTIzNDU2Nzg5JXUyMDFEbCV1MjIxQXUlQjJtJXUyMjFBbEglQkIlN0IldTAxMDElM0JsJXUyMDdFJTNBQSV1MjIyQkJhJTdCYkl3RklXaEZiJXUwMTdFJTNCRkliSUAldTAxN0UlN0QlN0QlM0IlN0QlQjlLJXUyMDc0JTdCJXUwMTEzMiU1QyV1MjMyMSVCMWUlN0JAJXUwMzlBJTdEJTNCJXUyMDc0JXUyNTNDJXUyNTNDJTdEJTNCMEUlN0IldTAxMTMyJTVDJXUyMzIxJXUyMTE2JTNBaCsrJTdEJXUyNTVB)
is a a test-suite for that.

70 bytes [`√lH»{ā;l⁾:A∫Ba{bIwFIWhFbž;FIbI@ž}};}¹K⁴{ē2\⌡±e{@Κ};⁴┼┼};0E{ē2\⌡№:h++}╚`](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=MTIzNDU2Nzg5MCV1MjAxRCV1MjIxQWxIJUJCJTdCJXUwMTAxJTNCbCV1MjA3RSUzQUEldTIyMkJCYSU3QmJJd0ZJV2hGYiV1MDE3RSUzQkZJYklAJXUwMTdFJTdEJTdEJTNCJTdEJUI5SyV1MjA3NCU3QiV1MDExMzIlNUMldTIzMjElQjFlJTdCQCV1MDM5QSU3RCUzQiV1MjA3NCV1MjUzQyV1MjUzQyU3RCUzQjBFJTdCJXUwMTEzMiU1QyV1MjMyMSV1MjExNiUzQWgrKyU3RCV1MjU1QQ__) works too, but as I only now implemented [`√` on strings](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/c91057455cb528be96db5c5f5d3d93b9bdb06f80/P5ParserV0_12/data/charDefs.txt#L442-L443) and the documentation didn't mention that it would floor the length I won't count it.

Explanation:

```
creating a square from the input

l       get the length of the input
 √      get its square root
  u     floor that
   ²    square it
    m   mold the input to that length
     √  convert it to a square

creating the unfoldings of the square - the idea is to cut out the inner squares to a new array

lH»{                              } (length-1)//2 times do
    ā;                                push an empty array below ToS
      l⁾                              push ToS.length - 2 (ToS here is the square or the previous unfolding)
        :A                            save a copy of that in the variable A
          ∫B                    }     repeat that amount of times, saving iteration on B - cutting the inner square to the empty array
            a{                 }        variable A times do
              bIw                         get the b+1th row of the previous unfolding
                 FIW                      get the (current loops iteration + 1)th character of that
                    h                     swap the 2 items below ToS - so the stack now is [..., prevUnfolding, newArray, character]
                     Fbž                  at [current loops iteration; b] insert that character in the array
                        ;                 swap the top 2 items - the stack now is [..., newArray, prevUnfolding]
                         FIbI@ž           at [current loops iteration+1; b+1] insert a space
                                 ;    get the now not empty array ontop of the stack

add the horizontal unfoldings

¹                    wrap the stack in an array
 K                   push the 1st item of that, which will function as the canvas
  ⁴{              }  iterate over a copy of the remaining items
    ē2\⌡               repeat (e++ divides by 2) times (default for the variable E is the input, which defaults to 0)
        ±                reverse the array horizontally
         e{  }         repeat e times
           @Κ            add a space before ToS
              ;⁴┼┼     add that horizontally before and after the canvas

add the veertical unfoldings

;                get the copy of the foldings above the canvas
 0E              reset the variable E to 0
   {         }   iterate the copy of the foldings
    ē2\⌡           repeat (e++ divides by 2) times (default for the variable E is the input, which defaults to 0)
        №            reverse the array vertically
         :h++      add that vertically before and after the canvas
              ╚  center the canvas vertically
```

Comment: Your 70 byte version is valid as [non-competing isn't a thing anymore](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12877/58974).

Comment: @Shaggy The 75 byte version is valid only because of that as before this challenge `√` only worked on numbers. The reason why I'm not counting the 75 byte version is because I feel like it falls under the loophole of adding a built-in just for a challenge

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>120</s> 109 bytes

```
ＡＩ§⪪ＩＸＬθ⁰·⁵.⁰ηＦη⊞υ✂θ×ιηＦ⁴«ＡυεＪ⁰¦⁰Ｆ÷⁺¹η²«Ｆ⁴«Ｆ⁻η⁺κκ§§εκ⁺μκ↷Ａ⮌ＥεＥε§ξνε¶»Ａ⎇﹪ι²Ｅε⮌λ⮌εεＡ⎇‹ι²⁻⁺²⁺κκη⁻η⁺κκκ¿﹪ι²Ｍκ¹Ｍ¹κ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU7bTsJQEPwj/6lWAZWbeEF5siRgJMQnE1@Mb9pYxJDG0p72gMnyvvzD/sD5hDrbgOYkO7s7szPHb3g9v@M1y1Ienpz9oFCiCOhs5uwnZxIsKJUgOUDDqbPvnMrkdTuSlyFnm2c21VKCb5rBYDvixNlIj7BbgNngOCeoKKbZXllhwUoxHoUUcsK5jhYwTmElX1Nn39QOBfyaV8AlFco93jsTsaG4YiHlQkuCvmLlziiLEE2Pdzka@J@K3J8/lzkmA8BP87L0Dv2j41q9cXJ61my1O93z3sXl1XX/5nbwCw) Note that `Ａ` has since been changed to `≔` and the link reflects this. Explanation:

```
       θ          Input string
      Ｌ           Length
     Ｘ  ⁰·⁵       Raise to the power 0.5
    Ｉ             Cast to string
   ⪪       .      Split on the decimal point
  §         ⁰     Take the first element (integer part)
 Ｉ                Cast to integer
Ａ            η    Assign to h
```

Calculates `h = int(sqrt(len(q)))`. (`Floor` was yet to be implemented...)

```
Ｆη⊞υ✂θ×ιη
```

Extracts the `h` slices of length `h` from the input. (Actually I don't bother truncating the slices to length `h`.) I use a `for` loop rather than a `Map` because I need to `Assign` the result of the `Map` somewhere and this is nontrivial when dealing with a `Slice`.

```
Ｆ⁴«
```

The unfolding happens 4 times, once for each direction (down, right, up, left as coded). The loop variable for this loop is `i`.

```
   Ａυε
```

Take a copy of the sliced string.

```
   Ｊ⁰¦⁰
```

Jump back to the origin of the canvas so that each unfold starts with the `h`-by-`h` square in the same place.

```
   Ｆ÷⁺¹η²«
```

Repeat `(h+1)/2` times; once for each unfold, plus once for the original square. The loop variable for this loop is `k`.

```
          Ｆ⁴«
```

Repeat 4 times, once for each side of the unfolded square. (I don't use the loop variable `l`.)

```
             Ｆ⁻η⁺κκ         Loop h-2k times, loop variable `m`
                    §εκ     Take the `k`th row
                   §   ⁺μκ  Take the `k+m`th column
                            Implicitly print the character
```

Print one side of the unfolded square. Since this is the `k`th unfold, the square's side is `h-2k`, and takes characters `k` away from the edge of the original square.

```
             ↷
```

Pivot ready to print the next side of the square.

```
               Ｅε       Map over the array (element `m`, index `n`)
                 Ｅε     Map over the array (element `x`, index `p`)
                   §ξν  Take the `n`th element of `x`
              ⮌         Reverse
             Ａ        ε Replace the array with the result
```

Rotate the sliced string. (Yes, that's a `ξ`. I don't get to use it often!) `Ｅη` would also work for the outer `Map`. The rotation also has the convenient side-effect of truncating the array's width to `h`.

```
             ¶»
```

After printing the side, the cursor moves off the edge of the square. Printing one character fewer fails for squares of side 1 and is less golfy anyway. Having previously pivoted, printing a newline conveniently moves the cursor back to the corner.

```
            ﹪ι²         Take `i` modulo 2
           ⎇            Choose either
                   ⮌ε   Reverse the array
               Ｅε       Map over the array (element `l`, index `m`)
                 ⮌λ     Reverse each element
          Ａ          ε  Replace the array with the result
```

Flip the square vertically or horizontally as appropriate.

```
           ⎇‹ι²                 If `i` < 2
                  ⁺κκ           Double `k`
                ⁺²              Add 2
               ⁻     η          Subtract `h`
                        ⁺κκ     Else double `k`
                      ⁻η        Subtract from `h`
          ≔                κ    Assign back to `k`.
```

Calculate the displacement to the next unfold.

```
           ﹪ι²          Take `i` modulo 2
          ¿             If not zero
              Ｍκ¹       `k` across and 1 down
                 Ｍ¹κ    Else 1 across and `k` down
```

Move horizontally or vertically to the next unfold as appropriate.

Here's a link to the 97-byte version obtained by making use of all the latest Charcoal features including `Floor`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZAxb8IwEIVn8issJltyK0Dt1AkJVaIqUkQZu4TkiN04NthOgFb57enFSRDtdLn43XfvXSoSm5pEte3SOZlr@qqMsTQ2Z7D0HXTuBT0xTmaPzwyLYC/RwVhCBSNx5QStOPlQMgV64mQnS3BUdio26p4Y@YkmAxvFgA@Tt6o87gydIbZrg3Ct/UrWMgP8Si2UoD1kuIaTBQuMyR1vaDZSV44KTmKFteCkwMUktlJ7uvRrncHlVqF7HZRlr3zpQLGsjd/KXHja/xi8bqEG64BukmM3O5SRduFEI4ENgRATlk4/9TT0TXQD7cDqxF7xmC4cZ4FDvfGVqfYKQ94HLvorjxLMNqqKsK4IeHnA8CarlOmJw1E2pobuDPPeE3r@G2Z02xBQDu5m5iP4f3q4JcRETdS0bbJPMzjkQn4VqtTmeLLOV/X5cv1uH2r1Cw) Link is to verbose version of code.

Comment: Are you sure this works? TIO just seems to raise an error.

Comment: @LyricLy Bah, I thought I was being clever, but failed to actually check that it worked. I'll revert the change.

Comment: Crap forgot to make floats work in slices oops

Comment: @ASCII-only Doesn't help me, I need to truncate to integer before multiplying anyway.

Comment: Right. Well I'm adding floor soon so it won't be as much of a problem :P

Comment: @ASCII-only That's great! Out of interest, will you be adding ceiling too? (I'm guessing you might overload `⌊` and `⌈` to perform floor and ceiling if given float arguments.)

Comment: Yes (also O_o forgot I had those, was going to use lowercase/uppercase lol, thanks!)

Comment: Floor should work now :P

Comment: Wait hang on forgot to add verbose version, you'll have to use `Minimum` for a while I guess

Comment: @ASCII-only Right now it's very broken - the current link only works because of caching, I expect.

Comment: @Neil D: oops, it appears to be an edge case. I'll look into it ASAP.

Comment: @Neil Found it lol, typed `\1` instead of `\\1` for one of the replacements in the golfer

Comment: @ASCII-only Can confirm that `Floor` saves 5 bytes.